# gmaps.places_radar googlemaps.exceptions.HTTPError: HTTP Error: 404

Tags: google-maps

```
import googlemaps

google_key = "xxx"
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key = google_key)
radar_results = gmaps.places_radar(location = (25.0339687, 121.5622835), radius = 100, type = "train")

print(radar_results)
```

I got error as follow
raise googlemaps.exceptions.HTTPError(response.status_code)
googlemaps.exceptions.HTTPError: HTTP Error: 404

anyone has the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

From [(an ancient copy of) the documentation on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20180702055931/https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search):

> Notice: Radar search is deprecated as of June 30, 2018. After that time, this feature will no longer be available.

Radar Search is no longer available.